# Alternative to path module that always uses forward-slashes?

Tags: node.js

I've been (mis)using the native [`path`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module for manipulating URL paths (e.g. using `path.relative()` to work out the shortest relative link from one URL path to another). But this breaks on Windows, because `path` uses backslashes on Windows.

Is there an alternative to `path` that always uses forward-slashes, regardless of OS?

(There is a [url](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module but it doesn't have equivalents for `path.relative`, `path.dirname`, etc.)

Comment: FWIW OS-specific `path` functionality was added to the v0.12 branch as of [6a90a0600](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/6a90a060023dac4fc827613243e496237403f29f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

It looks like Browserify's [shim for path](https://github.com/substack/path-browserify) works well for this.

```
var path = require('path-browserify');
```

Works exactly like the native path module running on Unix, regardless of your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [slash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slash) module for this:

```
var path = require('path');
var slash = require('slash');

var yourPath = slash(path.join('foo', 'bar'));
// foo/bar
```